# Need help adding blank pages between title page and table of contents in PDF generated by Pandoc

Tags: pandoc

I am generating a PDF document using Pandoc, and I have a title page followed by a table of contents (TOC). I want to insert one or multiple blank pages between the title page and the TOC.

I've tried modifying the LaTeX template generated by Pandoc using the command `pandoc -D latex`. Here's the modification I made:

```tex
\newpage
\pagebreak
$if(toc)$
$if(toc-title)$
```

However, this modification doesn't seem to have any effect when I render the document with the custom template. In fact, it doesn't work regardless of where I place `\newpage` or `\pagebreak`.

Could someone please guide me on how to properly insert blank pages between the title page and the table of contents in my Pandoc-generated PDF? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: [Depending on the used the class](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), using `twoside` should already add this blank page (and in `oneside` mode a blank page wouldn't IMHO make much sense). Using `\cleardoublepage` could also help with `twoside`. `\newpage\pagebreak` does never make sense, because without any output (at least something like `\mbox{}`) the `\pagebreak` would be at the start of a new page and therefore ignores (similar to `\newpage` or `\clearpage` at the very beginning of a page).